# Browser "buffers" mouse events while paint/reflow

Tags: gwt, browser, user-input, paint, reflow

I am creating a GWT Application where I am displaying a list of elements, using a `CellList` and a `ListDataProvider`. The data I want to display in each Cell consists only of two strings. I created a custom Cell which extends from `AbstractCell`. To create my custom Cell I used UIBinder and created the UI based on HTML. Each Cell contains the two strings and a button. Clicking the button removes the element from the binded list. With my resolution, about 20 elements are visible, so I set the page size to 30 to have a little "buffer" when the user wants to scroll down. Here how the first three elements look like:

http://imageshack.us/f/201/listox.png/

No problems when running the deployed application on tomcat. But running in Development-Mode I noticed following problem when I am removing elements:

- I click on the "Remove element" button of the first element
- I click a second time on the "Remove element" button of the first element (while the first element still is visible)
- The first element is removed from the list
- The second element is also removed from the list

I tried the same withe the deployed version, but it was impossible for me to click the "Remove element" button of the first element twice, because it was removed too quick. So I increased the amount of displayed elements to 500, which resulted to the same problem.
I switched to a slower system (AMD G-T40R with 1GHz) and same happened to me setting the page size to 50 or more.

To dig further into this problem, I added a `NativePreviewHandler` and scheduled a `ScheduleCommand` via `Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred` in the `onBrowserEvent` method of my custom Cell to see what is happening. Here is the result (running in Development-Mode, Chrome 27.0.1438.7 dev-m, added a timestamp for checking the order):

- at 1363340977109 mousedown (on the "Remove element" button of the first element)
- at 1363340977206 mouseup (on the "Remove element" button of the first element)
- at 1363340977225 click (on the "Remove element" button of the first element)
- at 1363340981341 scheduleDeferred in onBrowserEvent
- at 1363340981366 mousedown (on the same position as the first click, but now on the "Remove element" button of the second element because the first was removed)
- at 1363340981386 mouseup (on the "Remove element" button of the second element)
- at 1363340981394 click (on the "Remove element" button of the second element)
- at 1363340985184 scheduleDeferred in onBrowserEvent

**Here the question:** Is it true that the second click is somehow "buffered" because the browser is busy rendering/(re)painting the content. Is there a way to determine when the rendering is done or to disable user-input while the browser is busy?

**My current solution/workaround:** I disable the buttons when an element is removed. So the clicks are ignored. To emulate that the browser finished rendering I added a certain amount of time (~50ms) after the `ScheduleCommand` is executed. Then I enable all buttons again. This works for now, but if someday the browser buffers the input for more than 50ms the problem occurs again.

Comment: I came acroll [`MozAfterPaint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/MozAfterPaint/). This event is not availaible per default and only works for Firefox. Unfortunately it also freezed my instance of FF when I tried it, so I am not looking futher into this.